# Lastlog not working properly

Tags: server, ssh, logging

currently my lastlog on ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-77-generic x86_64) is not showing all ssh-connects. This seems a bit wired to me.

My deploy-user connects via jenkins ssh:notty. This connections are looged in /var/log/auth.log

```
Jun  9 16:40:03 hostname sshd[31691]: Accepted publickey for deploy from 192.168.1.129 port 38718 ssh2: RSA SHA256
Jun  9 16:40:03 hostname sshd[31691]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user deploy by (uid=0)
Jun  9 16:40:03 hostname systemd-logind[2009]: New session 6764 of user deploy.
Jun  9 16:40:03 hostname systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user deploy by (uid=0)
Jun  9 16:40:04 hostname sshd[31691]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user deploy
```

But lastlog is not listing them:

```
username@hostname:~# sudo last
username     pts/0        192.168.1.25    Fri Jun  9 16:39   still logged in
username     pts/0        192.168.1.25    Fri Jun  9 16:39 - 16:39  (00:00)
username     pts/0        192.168.1.25    Fri Jun  9 16:37 - 16:38  (00:01)
username     pts/0        192.168.1.25    Fri Jun  9 16:25 - 16:28  (00:01)
```

and lastlog is telling me, that the user deploy never logged in:

```
deploy                                     **Never logged in**
```

So, what could lead to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's correct.

If you call a command without tty, e.g.

```
[root@myhost ~]# ssh monsoin001@otherhost.example.com mycommand
```

then the `wtmp`/`btmp` file will NOT be updated.